# Parsing file in a format of Key = Value in java

Tags: java, file, parsing

I'm trying to write a function that parse a file that each line is a key = value format. The file is .txt.
Does java has a specific class or object that can help me parse the file?

note- the file has about 500K lines.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you may check method [`Properties::load`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-), it will load the data into the current instance of Properties which is a map of String key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You can use a BufferReader to read the file line by line:

```
BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "myfile.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                // read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then parse the line by split over "="

```
String keyValue[] = line.split("=");
String key = keyValue[0];
String value = keyValue[1];
```

Then

Comment: This answer seems to not be finished yet. What is "then"?